# How do I keep my image from overflowing an inline-block container

Tags: html, css, image, formatting, inline

I have a website I am putting together for a client. Everything was going swimmingly until I ran into what seems like a simple problem, but one that I have never had to deal with before and can't find a solution to.

I'm trying to set up a 2 column deal with a heading and text on one side and an image on the other. I have my image and my text inside respective container divs. The divs have their display set to "inline-block" and thus, the image won't scale down to fit inside it's div. Is there a simple solution to this?

Here is the code:

HTML

```html
<div class="col">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Again, I know this is probably super easy (or completely impossible for some reason) but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `width: 100%` to the CSS.

```css
.col img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or you can put it in the `<img>` tag:

```html
<div class="col">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Image" width="100%">
</div>
```

The image will grow proportionally to the maximum width of the parent element. If you don't explicitly set the width, it will be presented in its original size.

Comment: I tried that, but it just stretches the image out, is there a way to do that and keep the aspect ratio?

EDIT: Never mind, I just had to add "height: auto;"

Thanks!